# How to programmatically send command

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following ICommand in my main window ViewModel.

```
RelayCommand busyIndicatorCommand;

public ICommand BusyIndicatorCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (busyIndicatorCommand == null)
            busyIndicatorCommand = new RelayCommand(BusyIndicatorCommandExecute, CanBusyIndicatorCommand);
        return busyIndicatorCommand;
    }
}
```

To call something like this from a child view is a simple process when in XAML and you have a button.

```
<Button Content="Press Me" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.BusyIndicatorCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding EnableIndicator}"/>
```

I would like to do the same thing, except from my ViewModel and there is no button. How would I do this?

**[EDIT] Final Solution**

Created a new class project

```
namespace Libs_SharedCommands
{    public class Commands
    {
        public enum CommandType
        {
            BusyIndicator
        }
        public static RoutedCommand cmd_BusyIndicator = new RoutedCommand();
    }
}
```

Added reference to it in my user control view model and execute it like so.

```
namespace UserControls
{
    class UserControlViewModel
    {

        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            setBusyIndicator(true);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Do stuff here
            })
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => setBusyIndicator(false)));
            });
        }

        private void setBusyIndicator(bool enable)
        {
            Libs_SharedCommands.Commands.cmd_BusyIndicator.Execute(enable, null);
        }

    }
}
```

And finally added the RoutedCommand handlers into my main window View which in turn calls the main window ViewModel. Fairly happy with this and MVVM is still intact.

```
namespace Application
{
    public partial class MainView
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CommandBinding cbBusyIndicator = new CommandBinding(Libs_SharedCommands.Commands.cmd_BusyIndicator, BusyIndicator_MainNavCmdExecute, MainNavCmdCanExecute);
            this.CommandBindings.Add(cbBusyIndicator);
        }

        private void BusyIndicator_MainNavCmdExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            setCommand(Libs_SharedCommands.Commands.CommandType.BusyIndicator, e.Parameter);
        }
        private void MainNavCmdCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void setCommand(Libs_SharedCommands.Commands.CommandType view_type, object parameter)
        {
            var viewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
            if (viewModel != null)
            {
                switch (view_type)
                {
                    case Libs_SharedCommands.Commands.CommandType.BusyIndicator:
                        viewModel.ShowBusyIndicator = Convert.ToBoolean(parameter);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Execute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the command:

```
BusyIndicatorCommand.Execute(EnableIndicator);
```

Comment: Sorry should have said that the child view/viewmodel is in another project and is loaded into the main window with reflection. So when using the button I am guessing, as I don't know exactly how it works, but it uses the visual tree to find the window, then it finds the ICommand in the windows view model. As such it doesn't know if there is a BusyIndicatorCommand out there. So I cannot just use BusyIndicatorCommand.Execute. Please let me know if any of this is unclear, my terminology may be out!

Comment: @Hank: But in the place where you want to call the command, is the type with the `BusyIndicatorCommand` in scope? If so, you could use the `as` operator to try and cast the `DataContext` to that type and if that is successful, access the `BusyIndicatorCommand`.

Comment: BusyIndicator is not in scope. Is something able to be loosely done?

Comment: @Hank: You can always use [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then use reflection methods such as [`GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.getproperties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the value of the `BusyIndicatorCommand` property - provided that you can somehow get the reference to the object that has that property (even if its actual type is not in scope).

Comment: What I mean by loosely is, instead of literally calling BusyIndicatorCommand is create like an event or something similar that bubbles up or tunnel down the visual tree? I have seen some tutorials that creating routed events like this for a button: public static readonly RoutedEvent SampleEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Tap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(SampleButtonSimple)); Could I implement something like this?

Comment: Sorry posted without seeing your last comment

Comment: @Hank: From your question, I understood that you want to call the command entirely within the view-model, without touching the view. Thus, there is no visual tree (that would be entirely located in the view).

Comment: Yes you are correct. Which why I am bouncing around all these ideas. Is there something similar to bubbling events for view models?

Comment: @Hank: That would depend on whether your view-model classes reference each other in some hierarchy. If they do, you can propagate method calls along your tree - but keep in mind that unless you know the type you're calling, you may still end up with something reflection-based.

Comment: No they don't reference each. I have another idea, is it possible to add a CommandBinding to a ViewModel? e.g: CommandBinding cbBusyIndicator = new CommandBinding(...);
this.CommandBindings.Add(cbBusyIndicator);

Comment: @Hank: You can add anything you like to your view-model, but the point remains that you need to somehow get a reference to the object that has the `BusyIndicatorCommand` property. In the view, this works because all nodes are linked in a tree hierarchy established by the pre-defined WPF classes. As the classes of your view-model are presumeably written by yourself and derive more or less directly from [`System.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you will have to supply all of that infrastructure yourself (or find a framework that does so).

Comment: @ormapper I understand now, and have a solution based on your information, which I have placed in an edit above